# Trying to access data from one class inside a other class

Tags: php, oop

Trying to get some data from one method in side static method(using it inside a other class) but I get the 'Using $this when not in object context in...' error.

Below a basic example

```
class mClass{

   public $someVar = 'Hello world...';

   public function passFunc(){
      $give = $this->someVar;
      return $give;
   }

   public static function showFunc(){
      $show = self::passFunc();
      return $show;
   }
}

mClass::showFunc();// show error: Using $this when not in object context in...
```

Comment: `$myclass = new mClass;` ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Answer (score 2):

You can't use $this, when you are working with static variables. $this is a pointer to the current object, but static variables belongs to class.

Answer (score 0):

A class method (or static function) isn't tied to a particular instance of your class, i.e. it doesn't have `$this` although `self` is available.

A class method can access static properties or methods, but accessing anything else within the class will raise an error. It's best to look at static methods as a means to organize functions; as such, they operate in between external functions and instance methods.

In your case, you'd have to create an instance inside your static method:

```
public static function showFunc()
{
    $o = new self;
    $show = $o->passFunc();

    return $show;
}
```